# how to assert nested lists using hamcrest java

Tags: java, nested-lists, hamcrest

I have some nested lists I would like to assert using hamcrest. 
Basically they are lists of items contained in a list.

e.g.

`List<List<String>> [[bed, bench, bookshelf], [book, bowl, basket], [bar, biscuit, smoked beef]]`

I would like to assert that every item starts with "b"

hasItem seems to stop matching after the first list.

`assertThat(list, hasItem(everyItem(startsWith("b"))));`

How can I do this in hamcrest?

I have tried contains as well.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut feeling is that you won't get there by using existing matchers.

But writing your own matcher ... takes only a few minutes, once you understand how things come together.

Maybe you check out another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156069/how-to-assert-that-a-list-has-at-least-n-items-which-are-greater-than-x-with-ha/39158396#39158396) of mine; where I give a complete example how one can write his own matcher. Back then, that took me maybe 15 minutes; although I had never written custom matchers before.

Comment: ah thanks very much for the prompt response. 

yes i was considering that and/or stepping through each list with a for loop.

I just thought there may be a 1 liner existing hamcrest matcher for nested lists.

Answer (score 1):

`hasItem` checks if there is *atleast one* item with the given condition. Your first inner list fulfills the condition, so hamcrest will stop.

As you figured out, `everyItem` checks .. every item.

Solution: `assertThat(list, everyItem(everyItem(startsWith("b"))));`
To please the compiler you have to cast `List<List<String>>` to `Iterable<Iterable<String>> list`