# Using hamcrest to compare a list of objects containing another list of objects

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I have the following object graph:

```
Order --> List of Lines --> List of Shipments object
```

The *Line* object has an attribute called *lineNumber*. The *Shipment* object also has an attribute called *lineNumber*. I don't know why they have it on both, but those are the cards I have been dealt with.

Would it be possible to compare that the `line.getLineNumber().equals(shipment.getLineNumber())` for each line?

So in effect, I want to test the following:

```
for(Line line : order.getLines(){
    for(Shipment ship : line.getShipments()) {
         assertEquals(line.getLineNumber(), shipment.getLineNumber());
    }
}
```

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

`assertThat(order.getLines(), everyItem(Matchers.<Line>hasProperty("shipments", everyItem(Matchers.<Shipment>hasProperty("lineNumber", is(line.getLineNumber())))))`

Obviously, I don't have a reference to line, so how would I compare the values in this case?

Answer (score 0):

**assertThat** takes exactly two parameters (well, three, but the third one would just be the message to print for fails):

1. actual value (so, yes, `getLines()`) is OK there
2. expected value, which should be some form of **matcher**

So your idea of adding **multiple** "expected matchers" to the **same** call simply doesn't work.

You got:

```
assertThat(a1, e1, e2, e3);
```

Instead: split up your single call with assertThat into several ones - one for each "expected" condition you want to check.

```
assertThat(a1, e1;
assertThat(a1, e2);...
```

If the above doesn't help, or if you wish to write code that only requires a single assertThat, you can always go forward and write your own customer matcher, for example starting with the simple solution I put together for some other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156069/how-to-assert-that-a-list-has-at-least-n-items-which-are-greater-than-x-with-ha/39158396#39158396).

For the record: that was my first custom matcher, and I got it working in less than 10 minutes; in other words: that is a pretty easy task once you are into the concepts!

Comment: Fair enough. I don't have to do everything in 1 line, but I am still unsure if the lineNumber attribute at the line level can be compared with the one at the shipment level, without me explicitly saving the line number in a local variable in a for loop and then comparing that in the everyItem clause for  the Shipment object.

Comment: Then you are asking us to **interpret** your requirements; and your existing source code. Nobody around here can tell you **if** it makes sense to compare these values. If there is a constraint that they should be equal, then that it something within your context. We can only help with "how to do things"; not with "what to do". The "what" is **your** context.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but at least fits in one line:

```
    order.getLines().forEach(
        l -> 
          assertThat(l.getShipments(), 
             everyItem(
                  hasProperty("lineNumber", is(l.getLineNumber())))));
```

As you say, it could be great to have matchers holding references to the object being examined, but I would not know how to do it with Hamcrest.

Comment: yes that is along the lines that I was thinking on, but it seems hamcrest doesn't have the capability to hold references to the object as you mentioned. too bad !