# Look for a property in List of object using Hamcrest matcher

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, matcher, hamcrest

I have a Java POJO.

```
public class Emp {    
    private String name;
    private int id;
}
```

I have a list of employees (target):

```
 List<Emp> target = new ArrayList<Emap>();
 // Add emp object in list
 assertThat(target, containsInAnyOrder(????));
```

In **containsInAnyOrder**, I have to use something like i.e. hasProperty("name" , is(equalTo("John")). I have to check for a specific property in the list for specific value so what should be the syntax. I did not find any example of "containsInAnyOrder" with List of objects.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: OK, you got some updates; but maybe you find the other answer even more helpful. In any case, you got a lot of information by now ... should be good enough to get you going.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want a "generic" thing like: iterate a whole list; then retrieve a *field* of an object via **name**; to then check if any of the elements has a matching thing.

I think there is no such thing in Hamcrest: as that is ay too complicated for a pre-defined matcher.

In that sense, the only "answer" to exactly this requirement would be to create your **own** customer [matcher](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2012/03/07/create-your-own-matcher/) that uses reflection to actually do that.

More details: you can start with an older [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156069/how-to-assert-that-a-list-has-at-least-n-items-which-are-greater-than-x-with-ha/39158396#39158396) of mine that contains a ready to use matcher that works for lists.

Actually, the only thing left to do now: change my list matcher to perform a different kind of check. And there you could make use of the Apache Commons EqualsBuilder listed in the other answer.

There should be no big hurdle in implementing that; its just "work".

But: I am not sure if that is really the correct approach. As said; the question you are trying to solve there sounds **very** specific too me; and you know: any unit test that uses reflection lacks the same problem that any "reflection based" code has - the compiler will not tell you, when somebody changes your production code; for example by changing the name of the field `name`.

Thus: instead of using reflection, I would rather compromise on the "production code" side of things; for example by adding a simple getter:

```
public class Emp {
... fields
  String getName() { return name; }
```

And instead of using reflection to compare generic properties, you write a matcher that knows to use that getter to fetch names and compare them.h

Comment: Yes plz. I thought it should be present. Help me out.

Answer (score 1):

If your object-to-compare is always as simple as a Java Pojo, then maybe you can take a look of [EqualsBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) from Apache Commons Lang3. In particular, this method:

```
public static boolean reflectionEquals(Object lhs, Object rhs, boolean testTransients)
```

You can implement your own "equals" matcher which delegates the comparison to `reflectionEquals`.

To do that, you subclass the `TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher<T>` class from Hamcrest.

```
class ReflectiveEqualsMatcher<T> extends TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher<T> {

    private final T other;

    public ReflectiveEqualsMatcher(T divisor) {
        this.other = divisor;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(T me, Description description) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(me, other, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
    }

    public static <T> ReflectiveEqualsMatcher<T> same(T other) {
        return new ReflectiveEqualsMatcher(other);
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
//static import ReflectiveEqualsMatcher.same first
assertThat(target, containsInAnyOrder(same(obj1), same(obj2), same(obj3)));
```