# JUnit compare objects in collections except specified fields in contained objects

Tags: java, junit, mocking, hamcrest

JUnit tests...

It needs to compare 2 single elements excepting some fields. I can use [assertj](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#field-by-field-comparison) for this:

```
Assertions.assertThat(actual).isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(except, "id", "innerCollection");
```

and it works good. But it's not enough. I need to compare inner collections also. I know that only ids are different in inner collection. Is it possible to compare ones like

```
Assertions.assertThat(to.getInnerCollection()).isEqualToIgnoringGivenFields(from.getInnerCollection()
, {except fields in collection elements});
```

Comment: I am glad that you found my answer helpful :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would rather consider to create your own custom matcher.

That is actually a straight-forward task; you can find a detailed example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156069/how-to-assert-that-a-list-has-at-least-n-items-which-are-greater-than-x-with-ha).